# getting menu press item and passing it to recycler view to set variable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a navigation drawer set up with different categories. I also have a recycler view that gets the post from firestore (already segregrated in categories) and loads and displays them. my issue is that I want it so when the user presses on that menu item it loads the posts from that category in firestore and displays them. I have attempted to use bundles but have not figured out how to successfully get it to load

adapter:

```
        @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

        blog_list = new ArrayList<>();
        blog_list_view = view.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_view);

        // blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);
        blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(getContext(),blog_list);
        blog_list_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        blog_list_view.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);



        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore.collection("politics").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                for(DocumentChange doc: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                        BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);
                        blog_list.add(blogPost);

                        blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

            }
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

you can see here where it says "politics" is where i need to get the proper menu item to load

navigation drawer:

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, user_profile.class);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SettingsFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_sign_out:
            Toast.makeText(this, "SIGNED OUT TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            sendToStart();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_new_post:
            Intent postIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewPost.class);
            startActivity(postIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_politics:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new CategoriesFragment()).commit();
            break;
```

the adapter works fine i just cant figure out how to pass the data to the adapter to load the specif category based on what menu item was selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, inside your `onNavigationItemSelected`, add the info to your `CategoriesFragment` via a bundle:

```
case R.id.nav_politics:
    CategoriesFragment fragment = new CategoriesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("collection", "politics");
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
       .beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
       .commit();
    break;
```

Next, inside your fragment's `onCreate` or `onStart` (not sure about `onCreateView`) get the string from the bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    String collection = bundle.getString("collection", "");
}
```

You can then use it for your Firestore collection.

A future improvement would be extracting `politics` to a static variable. Another (if passing different values for `collection`) would be making a helper function you can just pass the `collection` value to so multiple nav items can use it without code duplication.